# iCloud unnecessarily syncs files

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization

I store about 800,000 files in iCloud with about 500 GB. Two days ago, the Mac Mini started seemingly re-uploading all local files to the iCloud, even though I was only working on a few files at the time.

Currently, the status indicator in the Finder is at about 330,000 changes and just under 100 GB, and it's continuing to increase (very slowly).

Biggest problem right now is that the latest file changes have not been synced to iCloud for two days, but I need them on another computer. I tried using `brctl evict` to force a sync by deleting them, but that was rejected.

Sure I could copy the files manually now, but I'm actually hoping that there is some way to cancel this apparent full sync.

On some web pages it is mentioned that such a synchronization can happen if the computer has not been used for a long time. But that can't be the case here, the computer is used daily.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get `bird` to cancel the ongoing full synchronization?